# Integrating Product of nth-Order Polynomial and Exponential of 2nd-Order Polynomial

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

For the $n$-th order polynomial $p_n(x)$, I want to calculate this integral:

$$\int_0^1 p_n(x)e^{-a(x-b)^2}dx$$

I wasn't able to find any solutions. If a solution for this or a simplified variation of it already exists, I'd really appreciate it if you can direct me to it.

**What I've tried:**

One way I have tried is to unpack $p_n(x)$ and calculate:

$$f_k(x)=\int x^ke^{-a(x-b)^2}dx$$

Then, I tried to solve this using integration by parts. Let:

$$g_k(x)=x^ke^{-a(x-b)^2}$$
Then:
$$\frac{dg_k(x)}{dx}=kg_{k-1}(x)-2ag_{k+1}(x)+abg_k(x)$$
Integrating on both sides, we get:

$$g_k(x)=kf_{k-1}(x)-2af_{k+1}(x)+abf_k(x)$$

Cleaning it up and dropping $(x)$ for readability:

$$f_k=\frac{b}{2}f_{k-1}+\frac{k-1}{2a}f_{k-2}-\frac{1}{2a}g_{k-1}$$

Now this is a nonhomogeneous recursive sequence with variable coefficients. Note, that $f_0$ and $f_1$ can be computed somewhat analytically based on the error function. To solve the sequence, I'm trying to apply [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110265/recurrence-relation-with-variable-coefficients). But, this method itself leads to messy integrations. Is there more straight-forward way to solve any of these steps?

**Special Case**

If $b=0$, we can simplify $f_k$ to the [lower incomplete gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) function:

$$\int_0^1x^ke^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a}^{k+1}\gamma(\frac{k+1}{2},a)$$

I wonder if gamma function would be part of the general answer as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that $p(\sqrt{a}u + b)$ is a polynomial in $u$, so you really only need $\int x^k e^{-x^2}dx$.